# haskell-language-server 0.3.0 for GHC 8.10.2 is not available on Windows_NT

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, ghc

So I installed Haskell using Chocolatey on Windows 10 on another drive and GHC, GHCi, Cabal, and Stack are all working perfectly using Powershell. I am currently coding some solutions without using Stack, just plain GHC, using VS Code and installed the Haskell extension and also HLink. However, upon start of VS Code, an error message pops up:

```
haskell-language-server 0.3.0 for GHC 8.10.2 is not available on Windows_NT
```

which is weird 'cause I have haskell-language-server on my PATH at `%APPDATA%\Code\User\globalStorage\haskell.haskell` and also, the version of my GHC is 8.10.2.

Does anyone have an idea on what could the problem be? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that my version of GHC is 8.10.2 which is not yet supported by Haskell-Language-Server 0.3.0. I can either

1. Wait for a new version of HLS to come out
2. Downgrade my GHC to 8.10.1
3. Compile HLS from source.

Comment: 0.5.1 now supports ghc 8.10.2, so you can try upgrading your project now